# Array of objects returns length = 0

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, async-await

I execute requests to the server and add them to the array of objects in the service:

```
async auth(login: string, password: string) {
    let data = this.ApiService.autorization(login, password);
    data = (isNullOrUndefined(await data)) ? [] : await data;
    this.ApiService.cars = data['cars'];

    for (let i = 0; i < this.ApiService.cars.length; i++) {
        let car = this.ApiService.cars[i];
        this.http.get('http://get/example/').subscribe((data) => {
            this.ApiService.carsPosition.push(data[0]);
        });
    }
  console.log(this.ApiService.carsPosition)
  console.log('lenght: ' + this.ApiService.carsPosition.length)
}
```

The console displays the following data:
[image]

The data is received, but their length is zero. And I can’t use them. What to do?

Comment: You should `await` the `this.http.get('http://get/example/)` call, not subscribe an asynchronous callback to it!

Comment: It's an `Observable` btw

Comment: Probably you can't await the data twice, but that's not the reason

Comment: Are you sure, because the logged array seems to have the correct length. There probably is a problem somewhere else.

Comment: How can this structure be organized?

Comment: I need all the parameters in the loop to be received and written to the array

Comment: @ChayimFriedman You can `await` a promise as often as you want, it will always have the same result. (Admittedly, it would still make more sense to just write `let data = await this.ApiService.autorization(login, password);`)

Comment: @LearnforFun The [expansion shown in the console screenshot happened after the data was loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4057440/1048572), but that doesn't mean it's immediately available after the requests were started.

Comment: @Bergi What are you trying to say? I merely pointed out that the logged array (of objects) had the correct length.

Comment: @LearnforFun I'm saying that it has the correct (expected) contents *at the wrong time*. No, this is not a problem elsewhere, it's a problem right in the posted code. As you can see in the first line of that screenshot, the array (`[]`) is empty when it gets logged.